# How to display only one country or a specific area in Google maps using the api?

Tags: php, javascript, api, google-maps

I am using Google Maps in a project and I want to display only a country map in my map window i.e. I want only the US to show on my map not Canda and Mexico and so on, cutting away the superflous information for the app I am building.

I found some stuff where you can restrict the area covered with some javascript however this still gives me a lot of extra map area as geographic areas usually do not conform to squares.

Further on I am limited by time, $, php and javascript so I can't really do some fancy custom solution that involves lots of work i.e. the usual setting.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Check out one of [Mike Williams](http://econym.org.uk/gmap/range.htm)' great GMaps tutorials: in there, he shows how to limit zoom and pan in your map.

If you want some areas to be non-visible, [try this one:](http://econym.org.uk/gmap/einsertg.htm) I think that's closest to what you want (the [example](http://econym.org.uk/gmap/example_egroundoverlay.htm) actually does the same thing you want, but it seems to be geared towards Canadians ;)).

Comment: Not exactly to the point but close enough, upon googling about it, it seems that it's not supported in the google maps api.