# Showing particular country using google chart map

Tags: jquery, google-visualization

I need to show a country specific map which show a country map with all their provinces.and for that I am using Google chart maps .here is my code

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["geomap"]});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawMarkersMap);
function drawMarkersMap() {
          var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
            ['State', 'Data'],
            ['West Bengal', 5],
          ]);

          var options = {}
          options['region'] = 'IN';
          options['displayMode']= 'regions';
          options['resolution']= 'provinces';



          var container = document.getElementById('map_canvas');
          var geomap = new google.visualization.GeoMap(container);

          geomap.draw(data, options);
        };

  </script>
    </script>
```

It shows the map but problem is it does not show a particular country it shows the whole region,here is the image link of output map [Link for output map][1].

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0Bwgb6kIgn-H9MXIwZ3BWTk1HRW8/edit?usp=drivesdk

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to display only one country or a specific area in Google maps using the api?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/717019/how-to-display-only-one-country-or-a-specific-area-in-google-maps-using-the-api)

Comment: I am talking about map charts here not google maps