# How to Use google places api in android with restrict particular place?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-api, google-places-api, android-googleapiclient

Hey Guys i basically i want to create one application that have Autocomplete TextView and show place according user search i just restrict user show only india's city name not other. 
can any one know ?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/717019/how-to-display-only-one-country-or-a-specific-area-in-google-maps-using-the-api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To search places bounded to only India , you can use **setBoundsBias()** in your code.Google now provides Autocomplete widget which makes things even simpler.
Please see this link:
**https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/autocomplete**

Answer (score 0):

Create a filter and setCountry as India in the filter and set the filter in the PlaceAutoComplete fragment or intent.

```
AutocompleteFilter typeFilter = new AutocompleteFilter.Builder()
    .setCountry("IN")
    .build();
autocompleteFragment.setFilter(typeFilter);
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
try {
                AutocompleteFilter typeFilter = new AutocompleteFilter.Builder()
                        .setTypeFilter(AutocompleteFilter.TYPE_FILTER_ADDRESS)
                        .setCountry("au")
                        .build();
                Intent intent = new PlaceAutocomplete.IntentBuilder
                        (PlaceAutocomplete.MODE_FULLSCREEN)
                        .setFilter(typeFilter)                         
                        .build(ProfileActivity.this);
                startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_SELECT_PLACE);
            } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException |
                    GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```